# I can't get my delete function to delete items off the list

Tags: c++, function, header-files, function-call

When I add a person it gets added correctly, but when I go to delete the name it says the name is not found. This program allows a user to create a phonebook and edit information in the phonebook

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "PhoneBook.h"
using namespace std;
char MenuSelection ();

int main() {
    char Selection;
    PhoneBook myList;
    do{ 
        Selection = MenuSelection ();
        switch (Selection){
            case 'a':
                myList.AddEntry ();
                break;
            case 'd':
                myList.DisplayNamesAndNumbers( );
                break;
            case 's': 
                myList.FindEntry ();
                break;
            case 'r':
                myList.DeleteFunction ();
                break;
            case 'q': 

                break;
            default : 
                cout << "\n\nNot a command choice\n";
                cout << "Press enter to continue";
                cin.get();
                cin.get();
                system ("clear");
        }
    }while (Selection != 'q');
    myList.MakeFile ();
    cout << "Press enter to continue";
    return 0;
}

//This function prints out the opening menu and allws users to enter a command.
char MenuSelection (){
    char Response;
    cout << "\n                 MENU\n";
    cout << "a - add a name and phone number\n";
    cout << "d - display names and phone number\n";
    cout << "r - remove a name and phone number\n";
    cout << "s - search for a name and return the phone number\n";
    cout << "q - quit program\n\n";
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> Response;
    return Response;
}
```

Header file for above program

This is the class which allow the user to manipulate a phonebook.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int GROUPSIZE = 100;
struct contact {string NameEntry; string PhoneNumber;};

class PhoneBook {
private:
    int Size;
    contact ContactNumber [GROUPSIZE];
public:
    PhoneBook ();
    void MakeFile ();
    void AddEntry ();
    void FindEntry ();
    string DisplayNamesAndNumbers ();
    string DeleteFunction ();
};

//opens the file and adds names and numbers to the text file
PhoneBook::PhoneBook (){
    string PersonsName, PhoneNum;
    int i = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("phonebook.txt");
    if (!infile){
        cout << "File does not exist";
    }
    else{
        while (!infile.eof ()){
            infile >> PersonsName >> PhoneNum;
            ContactNumber [i].NameEntry = PersonsName;
            ContactNumber [i++].PhoneNumber = PhoneNum;
        }
        Size = i;
        infile.close ();
    }
}

//adds name and phone number to the list
void PhoneBook::AddEntry (){
    string PersonsName, PhoneNum;
    cout << "\n\nEnter the name to be added: ";
    cin >> PersonsName;
    cout << "Enter the phone number for " << PersonsName << ": ";
    cin >> PhoneNum;
    ContactNumber [Size].NameEntry = PersonsName;
    ContactNumber [Size].PhoneNumber = PhoneNum;
    Size++;
    cout << "Press enter to continue";
    cin.get ();
    cin.get ();
    system ("clear");
}

//finds names and numbers in the list
void PhoneBook::FindEntry (){
    int Location, Counter;
    string Contact;
    cout << "\n\nName to find: ";
    cin >> Contact;
    Counter = 0;
    while (Counter < Size){
        Counter++;
    //for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (strcmp(Contact.c_str (),ContactNumber [Counter].NameEntry.c_str ()))
            Location = Counter;
        else 
            Location = -1;
    }
    if (Location != -1)
        cout << "The phone number for " << Contact << " is " << ContactNumber [Location].PhoneNumber << endl;
    else
        cout << Contact << " not in phonebook\n";
    cout << "Press enter to continue";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    system ("clear");
}

//displays all information in the list
string PhoneBook::DisplayNamesAndNumbers (){
    string PersonsName, PhoneNum;
    int Check = 1;
    cout << "\n\nList is being sorted\n";
    while (Check == 1){
        cout << "Name\t\tTelephone Number";
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
            cout << ContactNumber[i].NameEntry << "\t\t" << ContactNumber[i].PhoneNumber << "\n";
        }
        break;
    }
    cout << "Press enter to continue";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    system("clear");
    return "";
}

//deletes information from the list
string PhoneBook::DeleteFunction (){
    char Answer;
    string PersonsName;
    int Location;
    cout << "\n\nName to remove: ";
    cin >> PersonsName;
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUPSIZE; i++){
        if (!strcmp(PersonsName.c_str (),ContactNumber[i].NameEntry.c_str ()))
            Location = i;
        else 
            Location = -1;
    }
    if (Location != -1){
        ContactNumber[Location].NameEntry = ContactNumber[Size].NameEntry;
        ContactNumber[Location].PhoneNumber = ContactNumber[Size].PhoneNumber;
        cout << PersonsName <<" removed from phonebook\n";
        cout << "Press enter to continue";
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        system("clear");
        return"";
    }
    cout << "Name not found in phonebook\n";
    cout << "Press enter to continue";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    system ("clear");
    return"";
}

//closes the file at the end of the program
void PhoneBook::MakeFile (){
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("phonebook.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUPSIZE; i++){
        outfile << ContactNumber[i].NameEntry << " " << ContactNumber[i].PhoneNumber<<"\n";
    }
    outfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Whoah, way too much code. And poorly formatted to boot. Can you isolate just the part that is confusing you?

Comment: string PhoneBook::DeleteFunction (){
    char Answer;
    string PersonsName;
    int Location;
    cout << "\n\nName to remove: ";
    cin >> PersonsName;
    for (int i = 0; i < GROUPSIZE; i++){
        if (!strcmp(PersonsName.c_str (),ContactNumber[i].NameEntry.c_str ()))
            Location = i;
        else 
            Location = -1;
    }

Comment: if (Location != -1){
        ContactNumber[Location].NameEntry = ContactNumber[Size].NameEntry;
        ContactNumber[Location].PhoneNumber = ContactNumber[Size].PhoneNumber;
        cout << PersonsName <<" removed from phonebook\n";
        cout << "Press enter to continue";
        cin.get();
        cin.get();
        system("clear");
        return"";
    }
    cout << "Name not found in phonebook\n";
    cout << "Press enter to continue";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    system ("clear");
    return"";
}

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to "break" in your delete after finding the match.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using `strcmp` wrong. It return `0` if both strings match, so you need `strcmp() == 0`. Have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) for the possible return values.
Next, since you're already using `std::string`s, just compare those directly, they support it:

```
if(Contact == ContactNumber[Counter].NameEntry)
```

Also, you're not breaking out of your for-loop after finding the entry you want to delete.

---

Another side-advise: Your phonebook can contain duplicate entries, since you're not checking if the person already exsists in your `AddEntry` function.
And lastly, after you've gone through all this pain of maintaining what is basically a mapping from one string to another, for your further uses of such a data structure, consider using `std::map`. :)

```
#include <map>

int main(){
  map<string /*name*/, string /*number*/> phonebook;
  phonebook["Meyers"] = "03024233";
  string number = phonebook.find("Meyers");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contact ContactNumber [GROUPSIZE];
```

With the current implementation, I think it won't delete an entry from the array of objects. You have `GROUPSIZE` number of `contact` objects( i.e., an array of objects ). Array cannot be modified in size. If you need to remove an element from an array, first you need to have a reference of type `contact`.

```
contact *ContactNumber ;  // new it with GROUPSIZE number of objects in PhoneBook constructor.
```

If you need to delete an element at `m` position, you need to make `GROUPSIZE - m` translations using copy-swap rule. i.e., `m+1` position object should be in `m` position, `m+2` position object should be in `m+1` position, .... is the correct way of implementation, I think. And remember to `delete[] ContactNumber;` in the destructor of `PhoneBook` to avoid memory leaks.

To keep all the pain out, use a `std::vector` instead.